# Finding the probability that a particular trajectory occurs

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Consider an infection process starting from the origin of a d-dimensional hyper-cubical lattice. The process evolves as follows:
If a site is infected, it infects its neighbours with rate $r$ i.e. in time $dt$ the infinitesimal probability of infection is $rdt$.
At time $t=0$, only the origin is infected. Suppose we look at all possible trajectories of this process that start at the origin and end at some specified point at time $t$. How can we go about assigning weights (probabilities) to these trajectories?
From what I understand, in the evolution of this infection, some trajectories should be more likely than others (one can always think of pathological examples).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If there are any clarifications needed, I'll be happy to provide them :)

Comment: What you have is sort of like a branching random walk that takes steps after an exponential time. Do you want to understand the distribution of "individual genelogies of infection", i.e. paths of the infection process (ignoring backtracking?) or the distribution of the maximal extent of the infection, or something else? Each "infinite trajectory" is probability zero since there are uncountably infinitely many of them. Eventually (as time goes to infinity) the entire lattice is infected as you have not specified anything about recovery.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. Indeed this is a branching random walk where the time to take a step is given by an exponential distribution.
Suppose we ignore recovery (infected sites are infected forever), I want to look at the distribution of the individual genealogies of infection (as one would say in the language of branching processes). Is there a known way to do it?

Comment: Well, it really depends precisely on what your are looking for. Each step is equally likely, so all finite paths of $n$ steps are equally likely, but that includes backtracking over already infected sites. It sounds like you want to ignore steps back to already infected sites though.

Comment: Oh, this is the $d$-dimensional contact process with death rate zero. It's been studied very well.

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks a lot! :) I had been thinking about this problem for quite some time but couldn't come up with an elementary way to do so.

Comment: While this is indeed the $d$-dimensional contact process, I don't see this question being answered in their literature either.

Comment: I guess this problem is something like a self-avoiding branching random walk and there probably doesn't exist a known way to calculate weights of the configurations.

Comment: Yes, depending on how precise a formula you want for "the probability distribution of paths", you may not be able to get it. But you can get bounds on the growth and other things. I believe the first chapter in "Durrett, R. (1988) Lecture Notes On Particle Systems And Percolation" covers this process some. You'll have to find the book in a library though.